# Can not connect to the FTP (hosting) - Windows - port 21 issue

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, port

Here is the weird problem I have. I suddenly can't connect to any of my 2 FTP (hosting servers) (port 21) through my Windows 10.

It took me two whole days now, and I just can't find out, where the problem lies!

This is what I did until now:

- I opened the 21 port on the router (suspected router update...).
- I opened the port 21 in the Windows Defender (in and out).
- I deinstalled and reinstalled the firewall (Commodo) and tried without it and with a fresh installation.
- I tried with the free FTP programs (Filezila, WinsSCP and Cyberduck) in active and passive mode.
- Telnet result: Could not open connection to the host, on port 21: Connect failed

What the hell is going on??? What else can I try??

---

Tried with the port 20, tried over the phone WLAN as well, I got 20 sec timeout “error” and I tried to set timeout to 0 as well 200 sec. No connection, just a different “error”: Connection attempt failed with "ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out".

---

Tried with the port 20, tried over the phone WLAN which does not run over the service provider so the service provider. I got 20 sec timeout “error” and I tried to set timeout to 0 as well 200 sec. No connection, just a different “error”: Connection attempt failed with "ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out". Until now, I have managed to eliminate these options:

- Service provider (same results over the Phone network)
- Windows Defender Firewall (Ports 20,21 opened in and out)
- Comodo Firewall (Deinstalled restarted, ran Comodo cleaner, restarted and tried without any kind of firewall etc.)
- Router (opened port 20,21, disabled firewall)
- Telnet can´t connect trough port 21
- Tried 3 diferent FTP clients to connect to 2 different hosting servers and my own VPS. Same timeout results (Telnet...).

Comment: Is the server hosted inside your network or outside (with respect to the router)? How were you "opening ports"? Do you have a different internet connection that you could test with? And do the servers respond on any other ports? (Could it be that your hosting provider stopped offering FTP in general?)

Comment: If you're connecting via the router - have you verified your port-forwarding rules on it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! All the THREE Hosting providers (on cPanel and Plesk and 3 different domains) blocked my FTP connection (probably some stricter Firewall settings issue). I just set up a new WHM VPS and FTP connects without any issues. It's just unreliable!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of frustration trying to connect to my ftp site for the last several months. Some days it worked and some days it didn't. My customers could connect with it when I couldn't, so I knew it wasn't a server issue. Yesterday I finally discovered that I could only connect with FTP when I was running my VPN. If VPN was off, I couldn't connect either with CuteFTP (free ftp client app) or using the Windows File Explorer technique. Once I turned on VPN, both techniques worked fine.

BTW, if you haven't tried the File Explorer technique, it's SO simple. You just type into the address line in File Explorer ->
ftp://yourFTPUserName:YourFtpPassWord@yourSite.com. If you know the home folder location that will bring, you can also specify sub-folders by adding "/myFolder/mySecondFolder" after the ".com" The only thing tricky about this for me has been that it is case sensitive. Otherwise this is a 10-second connection and your ftp folder looks and acts just like any other folder making it easy to manipulate files and folders. Hope this helps! If you have trouble, there are a couple of internet options in windows control panel that can block this usage. You have to have two options checked at Control Panel\ Internet Options \ Advanced \ Browsing: "Enable FTP folder view" and "Use Passive FTP (for firewall and DSL modem compatibility)". These are set by default on my Win 10 Pro installation, but I'm not on a domain here. If you are operating in a domain, the IT folks may be causing these to be off by default. But maybe you can change them?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).